# My return statement will not exit a recursive method

Tags: ruby, recursion, return, infinite-loop, roman-numerals

Simple Roman Numerals Algorithm solved using recursion.

I know the code get's into my if statement holding my base case. When I check the values using 'pry' everything is fine. However it just skips over my return statement and get's stuck in an infinite loop

```
 ROMAN_HASH = {
   1000 => "M",
   900 => "CM",
   400 => "CD",
   500 => "D",
   100 => "C",
   90 => "XC",
   50 => "L",
   40 => "XL",
   10 => "X",
   9 => "IX",
   5 => "V",
   4 => "IV",
   1 => "I"
 }

   def roman(num, output="")
      return output if num <= 1
    else
      ROMAN_HASH.each do |k,v|
        roman(num - k, output+v) if num >= k
      end
    end
   end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4):

You need to *return* out of your `ROMAN_HASH.each` loop, or your recursive functions never end (at least, not for *huge* numbers of iterations). The problem is that you (seemingly) intended to return the *largest* value found in the `ROMAN_HASH` hash, but instead you iterate over all values, recursively calling `roman` for each one that is greater than `k`, do nothing with the result, and then return the `.each` iterator.

You're also misusing if/else. You can't mix post-if with an else expression.

Finally, you're stripping off the last digit by returning `if num <= 1`. You need to return `output` when `num < 1`, and if output is *equal* to `1` you should return `output + 'I'`, or just let the `else` branch handle this case:

```
def roman(num, output="")
  if num < 1
    return output
  else
    ROMAN_HASH.each do |k, v|
      return roman(num - k, output+v) if num >= k
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The OP should also be getting a "`else` is useless without `rescue`" warning, I think. In fact, that's a big part of the problem: the `else` is being interpreted as part of an implicit `rescue` block, i.e. it is being interpreted as code that should run when no exception is rescued … which in this particular method is "always", because *there is no* `rescue` block.